# Android - Including custom component causes it to be hidden behind main view

Tags: java, android, user-interface, layout

The app I'm working on has 4 tabs, 3 of which share many features, including a navigation bar a the bottom with Back, Edit, and Map buttons.  There is *exactly* the same xml in all 3 layouts, so I'm trying to DRY this out by extracting that xml into a separate component, including it, and then going from there.

Previously I had

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:id="@+id/showedit_toolbar"
                        style="@style/showItemToolbar">

            <ImageButton android:id="@+id/show_person_back_button"
                    style="@style/blackToolbarButton"
                    android:src="@drawable/left_white_arrow"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/show_person_map_button"
                    style="@style/blackToolbarButton"
                    android:text="map"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/show_person_edit_button"
                    style="@style/blackToolbarButton"
                    android:text="edit"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/show_person_map_button"/>                          
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"           
            android:layout_above="@id/showedit_toolbar"
            style="@style/CoinLightTheme">

// Lots more layout omitted
```

I extracted out the bit that's repeated into an xml file called show_toolbar.xml, changing the names of variables to make it more generic across the 3 views

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/show_toolbar"
    style="@style/showItemToolbar">

    <ImageButton style="@style/blackToolbarButton"
        android:src="@drawable/left_white_arrow"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:id="@+id/show_back_button"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/show_map_button"
        style="@style/blackToolbarButton"
        android:text="map"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/show_edit_button"
        style="@style/blackToolbarButton"
        android:text="edit"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/show_map_button"/>                         

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then from within my original layout file, I replaced that big block of code with

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <include android:id="@+id/show_toolbar" layout="@layout/show_toolbar"/>

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/showedit_toolbar"         
        style="@style/CoinLightTheme">
```

Now, the problem is that the view no longer shows up.  I can still click the buttons and they respond (i.e. if I click in the corner where the button should be, it still works), but I cannot see the buttons or bar onto which they were drawn.

I cannot find very good documentation on how Include is supposed to work, so perhaps I am using it incorrectly.  Any help would be appreciated

Before

[Before http://i34.tinypic.com/2dl0hm1.png](http://i34.tinypic.com/2dl0hm1.png)

After

[image: After]

Comment: Please crop your images to just the screen next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RelativeLayout` supports vertical stacking of widgets. According to your layouts, your "toolbar" will be hidden behind the `ScrollView`, AFAICT. If you do not want that behavior, adjust your layouts such that these do not overlap.

Comment: What I don't understand is the same layout works when it's directly included in the XML, vs included from an external file.

Comment: I think the same, I82Much. I don't understand